# Concurrent execution in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a Spark Streaming job to do some aggregations on an incoming Kafka Stream and save the result in Hive. However, I have about 5 Spark SQL to be run on the incoming data, which can be run concurrently as there is no dependency in transformations among these 5 and if possible, I would like to run them in concurrent fashion without waiting for the first SQL to end. They all go to separate Hive tables. For example :

```
   // This is the Kafka inbound stream
   // Code in Consumer 
   val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[..](...)

   val metric1= Future { 
              computeFuture(stream, dataframe1, countIndex) 
  }

 val metric2= Future { 
              computeFuture(stream, dataframe2, countIndex) 
  }
 val metric3= Future { 
              computeFirstFuture(stream, dataframe3, countIndex) 
  }

  val metric4= Future { 
              computeFirstFuture(stream, dataframe4, countIndex) 
  }

     metric1.onFailure {    
         case e => logger.error(s"Future failed with an .... exception", e)         
   }
    metric2.onFailure {    
         case e => logger.error(s"Future failed with an .... exception", e)         
   }
```

....and so on

On doing the above, the actions in Future are appearing sequential (from Spark url interface). How can I enforce concurrent execution? Using Spark 2.0, Scala 2.11.8. Do I need to create separate spark sessions using `.newSession()` ?